# How to create aspx pages into domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have users, they are signing in system. They have developed pages (using edit button and then press save button) but this is my CMS pages. I want to copy my single pages user by user to publish them. How to create dynamic aspx pages, with config files etc? How to add domain folder?

Comment: not sure you're going about it the right way, I don't think you need to be able to create a dynamic `aspx` page for a cms, your user created data should be stored in the DB or xml or something and displayed correctly in a templated aspx page.

Comment: CMS typically stores the content in DB and this is true for the pages as well. However there are options to deploy stuff onto physical directory but unless the Out of box options don't satisfy you, you should go the other route.

Comment: you need to url rewrite something like `user.aspx?username=johnsmith27` to `/users/johnsmith27` is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally there's no need to create aspx page or static html pages per user. What you need to do is store his/her post body and other necessary info in db and then create a main page to place user-specific data (like post body, posted-by,..) on it.

For example, you may have a route like this:

```
/post.aspx?userId=1
```

This page pulls data from database for the user of Id=1.

Comment: some blog sites or free CMS system has got add new page button? how do they make it?

Comment: Add New Page can have several meanings: It can be just a term used to add page content and then store it; only page content (html with pictures etc.) not the whole page. There are cms applications that create a static page for each entry you make. They get the data from user, generate a static page based on it, stream the page and finally store it in the file system on the server or database. But you should have a reason to do so as having one or a few smart pages (like post.aspx i mentioned above) with dynamic behaviour can handle most of basic/intermediate requirements of a common cms app.